# Add column named current date

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm creating an Access database to try to track average cost of inventory.  I want to make it to where when a button is clicked on the form a column is added to the table that is named with the current date and the word Quantity and another column is added with the current date and the word Price.  I can't just add columns named quantity and price because I am hoping to be able to use this over time.  So I want to know on mm/dd/yyyy we bought x widgets for y dollars a piece.  Then a week later I want to be able to hit the same button and add more lines with the new current date.  Is this even possible?  I'm using Microsoft Access 2016.  I've tried the following with some variations based on what I've researched but nothing seems to work.  AvgCost is the table name.  Also I'm very very new at this.

```
Private Sub Record_Button_Click()
ALTER TABLE AvgCost ADD COLUMN Quantity_DATE()
End Sub
```

I keep getting an error message reading "Compile Error: Expected: ENd of Statement and it highlights AvgCost

Comment: Rather than changing the design of your table by adding columns when you add new items, you should be adding new rows that contain the data. This is normally achieved using a form that is bound to the table, but may also be achieved by using a query or VBA.

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve. Probably you have the product in the first column. However trying to use Access like Excel where you just add new columns doesn't work. You will need the table AvgCost with columns ID, Product Reference, date, quantity, price. Then you need a table Product with ID, Product Name etc. to where you can reference your AvgCost records. No offense, but I recommend to read a tutorial about relational database design. Even though Access seems easy to configure it is still an SQL Database and not a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't run an SQL action in VBA like that. Certainly won't create a field with a date in field name. Need to call a command and concatenate date value.

`CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE AvgCost ADD COLUMN Quantity_" & Format(DATE(), "yyyymmdd") & " Number"`

However, this really is poor design. Instead of implementing procedure that routinely changes database structure, should be adding records.

Comment: Hi!  That worked, thank you very much!  I'll try to come up with a better way to design the database.  Like I said I'm new at this and kind of fumbling my way through it so this was the best I had come up with but I'll keep brainstorming.  Thanks again for your help and advice!